# Express: serve static files on subroute

Tags: express, url-routing, create-react-app

I'm trying to get routing work using Express and `create-react-app`.

My goal is to address the user to the homepage of the application when the URL is `/` and to the login page when the URL matches `/login`.

In my `server.js` I have two routes defined:

```
var mainRoutes = require("./routes/mainRoutes");
var apiRoutes = require("./routes/apiRoutes");

[...]

app.use("/", mainRoutes);
app.use("/api", apiRoutes);
```

While `apiRoutes` contains all the api routing definitions, `mainRoutes` is responsible for the main navigation (at least this was the idea):

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

let router = express.Router();

router.route("/").get((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "./client/build/" });
});

router.route("/login").get((req, res, next) => {
  res.send("This is the login page");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Somewhere I read about serving the static asset generated by the building process of create-react-app so I added:

```
// Priority serve any static files.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

// All remaining requests return the React app, so it can handle routing.
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"));
});
```

Adding these lines, I successfully see my index.html but I can't visit both `/login` and `/api`subroutes since it redirect me on the main page (index.html) each time.

It's like I need to serve the static files on my subroute `mainRoutes` but I don't have an idea on how to do that.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

`app.get('*')` would match every single route that you have.

You should do something like this:

```
var mainRoutes = require("./routes/mainRoutes");
var apiRoutes = require("./routes/apiRoutes");

[...]

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

app.use("/", mainRoutes);
app.use("/api", apiRoutes);

// If the app reaches this point, it means that 
// the path did not match any of the ones above
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  // redirect the user to where we serve the index.html
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: As soon as I add the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));` line, I'm not able to visit the `/login` page and the `/api` routes. I'm always been redirected to the main application.

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app I believe handles routing different, you cannot hook up the browser's route to the route you want to serve because you're running a single page application", unless you do universal routing with server and the js bundle

Comment: it doesn't work like html page routing, you're actually running a single page that literally changes the contents using javascript :D

Hope that helps you :>

Comment: "My goal is to address the user to the homepage of the application when the URL is / and to the login page when the URL matches /login"

when the url matches /login via user click on the application or JS or when they type it into the browser I believe the current behavior is to use hashrouting but that looks ugly or the universal rendering via the server rendering of react code.

There's cons to both but I think that will lead you on the right path. 

I don't know anything.. Q_Q

If anyone knows a solutuion love to hear it